# JMeter: Generate value for custom Header with a java class

Tags: java, header, jmeter

i try to test the performance for our api which has a request-limiter (100requets in 100sec otherwise the ip is blocked).
You can avoid this with a custom header. The value for this header is generate by a java class.

With jruby i can use "require" and "import" too use the class.

How can i do this for JMeter?

Additional infos:
the header value is dynamic -> for each request it has to be generated. 
To call HttpPwd.genPwd() two *.jar files are needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to proceed :

- Put the 2 Jars in jmeter/lib folder
- Put groovy-all.jar in jmeter/lib
- Use a JSR223 Preprocessor + Groovy
- Put in the Preprocessor the following code:

> import xxxxxx; // where xxxx is the full name of the HttpPwd class
>
> vars.put("header", HttpPwd.genPwd());

- On your request add a HeaderManager as a child and in its content put:

> HeaderName (I don't know what it is) : ${header}

Answer (score 0):

In your JMeter project navigate to `Thread Group` > `HTTP Request`. You can set your request parameters there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way of implementing this via [JMeter __Beanshell function](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-functions)

Assuming that you're having following logic for generating custom header:

```
package custom.header;

public class HttpPwd {

public static String getPwd() {
    return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
}
```

Which is accessible from some jar called "customheader.jar"

And you want to add a header named "MyHeader" to your request

1. Put customheader.jat to lib/ext folder of your jmeter installation. (or to location under search_paths or user.classpath if you have overriden these properties in your user.properties file)
2. Create a Thread Group
3. Add i.e. HTTP Request to Thread Group
4. In HTTP Request put Server Name or IP to be i.e. "google.com", Path - /, and add a parameter "q" with a value of "test". Actually it doesn't matter.
5. Add HTTP Header Manager AS A CHILD of HTTP Request
6. Add Name as MyHeader and Value - "${__BeanShell(import custom.header.*;HttpPwd.getPwd();)}"
7. Add View Results Tree listener after HTTP Request
8. Save and run

You should see something like:

```
GET http://www.google.com/?q=test

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
MyHeader: 1382360571781
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)
```

Mention MyHeader presense and value